# Orthogonal projection onto (general) simplex

Tags: convex-analysis, convex-optimization, convex-geometry

Let $v_0, \dots, v_n \in R^n$ be $n+1$ affinely independent points. Let $\sigma = \text{conv}(v_0, \dots, v_n) \subset R^n$ be a general simplex.

I'm interested in a fast method for computing the orthogonal projection 
$$
\arg \min_{u \in \sigma} ~ \|u-v\|.
$$

I know that for the probability simplex there exist efficient methods based on sorting. However I feel they do not extend to the general case.

Comment: Are you considering the standard Euclidean norm?

Comment: Yes, standard Euclidean norm.

Comment: I'm skeptical that there will be a fast method here. You're probably going to need to apply a general optimization method. The (likely) non-orthogonality of $v_1-v_0, v_2-v_0,\dots, v_n-v_0$ is what gets you. This is the very complication that motivates much of the development of first-order methods, including TFOCS, co-written by me.